# How can I catch a "catchable fatal error" on PHP type hinting?

Tags: php, fatal-error, type-hinting

I am trying to implement Type Hinting of PHP5 on one of my class,

```
class ClassA {
    public function method_a (ClassB $b)
    {}
}

class ClassB {}
class ClassWrong{}
```

Correct usage:

```
$a = new ClassA;
$a->method_a(new ClassB);
```

producing error:

```
$a = new ClassA;
$a->method_a(new ClassWrong);
```

> **Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to ClassA::method_a() must be an instance of ClassB, instance of ClassWrong given...**

Is it possible to catch that error(since it says "catchable")? and if yes, how?

Comment: For future reference: [Exceptions in the engine (for PHP 7)](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/engine_exceptions_for_php7) - Beginning with PHP 7 it is possible catch fatal errors. This is also for the here discussed *“Catchable fatal error”* (`E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`) as these be catched beginning with PHP 7..

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Update: This is not a catchable fatal error anymore in php 7. Instead an "exception" is thrown. An "exception" (in scare quotes) that is not derived from [Exception](http://docs.php.net/class.exception) but [Error](http://docs.php.net/class.error); it's still a [Throwable](http://docs.php.net/class.throwable) and can be handled with a normal try-catch block. see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/throwable-interface

E.g.

```
<?php
class ClassA {
  public function method_a (ClassB $b) { echo 'method_a: ', get_class($b), PHP_EOL; }
}
class ClassWrong{}
class ClassB{}
class ClassC extends ClassB {}


foreach( array('ClassA', 'ClassWrong', 'ClassB', 'ClassC') as $cn ) {
    try{
      $a = new ClassA;
      $a->method_a(new $cn);
    }
    catch(Error $err) {
      echo "catched: ", $err->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo 'done.';
```

prints

```
catched: Argument 1 passed to ClassA::method_a() must be an instance of ClassB, instance of ClassA given, called in [...]
catched: Argument 1 passed to ClassA::method_a() must be an instance of ClassB, instance of ClassWrong given, called in [...]
method_a: ClassB
method_a: ClassC
done.
```

---

Old answer for pre-php7 versions:
http://docs.php.net/errorfunc.constants says:

> E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR ( integer )
> Catchable fatal error. It indicates that a probably dangerous error occured, but did not leave the Engine in an unstable state. If the error is not caught by a user defined handle (see also [set_error_handler()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)), the application aborts as it was an E_ERROR.

see also: http://derickrethans.nl/erecoverableerror.html

e.g.

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if ( E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR===$errno ) {
    echo "'catched' catchable fatal error\n";
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

class ClassA {
  public function method_a (ClassB $b) {}
}

class ClassWrong{}

$a = new ClassA;
$a->method_a(new ClassWrong);
echo 'done.';
```

prints

```
'catched' catchable fatal error
done.
```

edit: But you can "make" it an exception you can handle with a try-catch block

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if ( E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR===$errno ) {
    echo "'catched' catchable fatal error\n";
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
    // return true;
  }
  return false;
}
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

class ClassA {
  public function method_a (ClassB $b) {}
}

class ClassWrong{}

try{
  $a = new ClassA;
  $a->method_a(new ClassWrong);
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
  echo "catched\n";
}
echo 'done.';
```

see: http://docs.php.net/ErrorException

Comment: So of course this behaves very much like a fatal error, except when you look in your server logs you won't find it. Thanks php :/

Comment: so in other words you can't catch a catchable error. Wonderful!

Comment: @Paul what brings you to this conclusion?

Comment: Oh, I just meant it wasn't catchable in the traditional sense (using a try/catch block). I was just feeling grumpy about PHP that day, so when I found out that it was 'catchable' in a totally different sense, I felt compelled to comment. Nothing against your wonderful answer (which in fact I upvoted); all my ire was for PHP itself!

Comment: And I thought I've overlooked something ;-) http://blog.codinghorror.com/php-sucks-but-it-doesnt-matter/ :D

Comment: Note, with ```try { ... } catch (\Throwable $thr) { ... }``` you can catch both Error-s and Exception-s.

Comment: I have PHP 7.0.12 and cannot catch `Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string` with any of `TypeError`, `Error`, `Exception` or `\Throwable` - any ideas?

Comment: @user9645 same here. Help please.