# check if item can be converted to string?

Tags: php, function, tostring

I am writing a debug method.

What I have is

```
if(is_xxx($item)){
 //echo output info for type
}
```

what I want to do at the end is

```
if(can_be_string($item))
echo $item;
```

Is there a `can_be_string` type function?

Comment: @Hailwood the only items I know that cannot become string are objects without `__toString()` method. Where do you get into problems?

Comment: What is the determinant of whether something can be a string or not? I don't understand the question.

Comment: I don't believe that a Resource can be cast to string either - not just objects (unless they have __toString) but I think those are the only exceptions

Comment: yeah, this function has no control over what is plugged into it. so someone could pass in for example a database resource, which could not be converted to a string.

Comment: Add a trap for is_null() as well if you're echoing rather than var_dumping... else you won't see what's echoed

Comment: @Mark Baker, @Hailwood Resources can be casted as string and will become something like "Resource id #X".

Comment: @Hailwood maybe of interest to you: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/PHP-Type-Casting.html

Comment: i suggest you to be clear about what do you mean by 'item'. Based in programming terminology do you mean _array item_ or just any given _value_? Also, you should be clear about what is "can be string", do you mean something that can  be concatenated with a string or casted as `(string)`? or also objects with "stringification" methods implementated?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ok, edited, with incorporating [Michiel Pater](https://stackoverflow.com/users/248756/michiel-pater)'s suggestion (who's answer is gone now) ans @eisberg's suggestions. `settype` will return `true` with objects no matter what, as it seems.

```
if(
    ( !is_array( $item ) ) &&
    ( ( !is_object( $item ) && settype( $item, 'string' ) !== false ) ||
    ( is_object( $item ) && method_exists( $item, '__toString' ) ) )
)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: Integers, double, float, ... can be casted as well. Arrays too, but without giving any useful information :-)

Comment: @eisberg: ugh, you are right of course! Let me check some of my own projects for this bug. LOL.

Comment: @eisberg: How's this then, in your opinion? Good call earlier by the way!

Comment: I would say if I really need to debug anything by hand an not by `var_dump()`, `var_export()`, `print_r()`, ... I would `switch`/`case` the `gettype()`.

Comment: I'm surprised `settype()` doesn't show up in http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: In PHP 8.0, your check for `__toString` can be replaced with `$item instanceof Stringable` So you could do `settype( $item, 'string' ) !== false  || $item instanceof Stringable` I really wish there was something nicer than having to do it all explicitly.

Comment: `settype` will raise a PHP notice when it fails.

Comment: I've never heard of `settype()` before; seems very PHP 3-ish. Since it works with `$item` by reference, I wonder if the value would be corrupted if it can't set it to string?

Answer (score 37):

For the sake of completion...

http://www.php.net/is_scalar, available since PHP 4; not a single word about it.. :)

Comment: Some objects can be cast to string. That is if they implement magical method `__toString()`. Also the note says it doesn't consider null value scalar for some reason. On top of that using this function on resources seems unreliable.

Answer (score 23):

How about

```
function can_be_string($var) {
    return $var === null || is_scalar($var) || (is_object($var) && method_exists($var, '__toString'));
}
```

And since **PHP 8** you can replace the third condition with `$var instanceof Stringable`

Comment: This will return the incorrect result if passed an object with a permissive `__call` function, see: https://3v4l.org/4ttLv. Use `method_exists` instead of `is_callable`

Comment: Also there are no drawbacks of using `method_exists` over `is_callable` since `__toString` must be public

Answer (score 10):

Quick and dirty implementation with test:

```
function canBeString($value)
{
    if (is_object($value) and method_exists($value, '__toString')) return true;

    if (is_null($value)) return true;

    return is_scalar($value);
}

class MyClass
{    
}

$object = new MyClass();
var_dump(canBeString($object)); // bool(false)

class MyClassWithToString
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

$objectWithToString = new MyClassWithToString();
var_dump(canBeString($objectWithToString)); // bool(true)

var_dump(canBeString(1)); // bool(true)
echo (string)1 . "\n";

var_dump(canBeString(false)); // bool(true)
echo (string)true . "\n";

var_dump(canBeString(1.0)); // bool(true)
echo (string)1.0 . "\n";

var_dump(canBeString(null)); // bool(false)
var_dump((string)null); // string(0) ""
```

Comment: I like this. I'm going to use it with `array_filter` to remove non-stringable items.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the shortest way I can find:

```
/**
 * Determine if we can cast a value to a string.
 *
 * @param mixed $v
 *
 * @return bool
 */
function can_be_string($v): bool
{
    return method_exists($v, '__toString') || $v === null || is_scalar($v);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

how about this decision?

```
function canBeString ($value) {
    try {
        $value = (string) $value;
    } catch (\ErrorException $exception) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I often go for this type of solution for such cases and up-voted accordingly, though on testing it out, it's a no go as it throws a 'Catchable fatal error' (in PHP 5 at least), which technically is not 'catch'able in the traditional sense for reasons that elude me - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple:

```
function can_be_string($var)
{
    return method_exists($var, '__toString') || (is_scalar($var) && !is_null($var));
}
```

The code has already been tested.
The `method_exists()` function returns `false` if `$var` is not an object, so this verification is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If is_string() doesn't help you, then I can only suggest some ideas:

- Trap strlen() or indeed another function that throws an error if the variable is not a string
- if not NULL, use to_string() and check if the string contains only numeric characters. If not (and the variable/object is a simple variable) you could assume something

Comment: I like using `if (strlen()) { // It's save to use where you expect a string. }`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think any of the answers were satisfactory.

Simplest implementation:

```
function can_be_string($value) {
    return (!is_object($value) && !is_array($value))
        || method_exists($value, '__toString');
}

class IsString {
    public function __toString() {
        return 'hello';
    }
}

var_dump(
    can_be_string(null), // true
    can_be_string(123), // true
    can_be_string(12.3), // true
    can_be_string('hello'), // true
    can_be_string(new IsString), // true
    can_be_string(new stdClass), // false
    can_be_string([1, 2, 3]) // false
);
```

Comment: This doesn't take numbers into account. They are perfectly valid to echo as strings.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson True, didn't read the topic properly, updated.

Comment: Under PHP < 8 this fails for a resource, right?