# Unable to catch a 'catchable fatal error' from QueryPath

Tags: php, try-catch, querypath

I have a script that scrapes some old HTML. It does about 1000 pages a day, and every so often it chokes for some reason and throws up the following error:

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument, null given, called in /var/scraper/autotrader/inc/QueryPath/QueryPath/CSS/DOMTraverser.php on line 417 and defined in /var/scraper/autotrader/inc/QueryPath/QueryPath/CSS/DOMTraverser.php on line 467
```

At first I thought it was the error was generated when htmlqp($html) was called, but I have wrapped it in a try{} statement and it didnt catch anything:

UPDATE:

I've found the offending line of code by using @ to see when the script would terminate without error. It's this line:

```
    try {
        $items = $html->find('.searchResultHeader')->find('.vehTitle'); //this one
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        var_dump(get_class($e));
        echo 'big dump'.$e->getTraceAsString();

    }
```

When it bombs out, it doesn't even echo 'big dump', so it really doesn't seem to be catching it.

I'm wondering if this is maybe a fault with QueryPath's error handling rather than my own?

Comment: Can anybody offer some insight into why this is not catching?

Comment: i don't know if it still necessary to someone, who need the solution requested to chekc http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$html->find('.searchResultHeader')->find('.vehTitle');
```

is the same as this:

```
$html->find('.searchResultHeader .vehTitle');
```

But without the risk of calling null->find();

If you really want to do it in 2 steps, use an `if`, not a `try`:

```
if($el = $html->find('.searchResultHeader')) $items = $el->find('.vehTitle');
```

Or maybe a ternary:

```
$items = ($el = $html->find('.searchResultHeader')) ? $el->find('.vehTitle') : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not catching because a standard try catch block will not catch errors of this type. In order to catch a 'Catchable' fatal error a [Set Error Handler](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) for the E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR is needed.

See Also: [How can I catch a “catchable fatal error” on PHP type hinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting).