# Pass interface as the arguent to some function

Tags: php, symfony, interface, interface-injection

I want to know. I found this in Symfony2 TranslationLoader class:

```
public function addLoader($format, LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    $this->loaders[$format] = $loader;
}
```

I found `LoaderInterface` there is only one method. But how we know the realization of this interface ? This is Interface Injection ?

Comment: If you're "injecting" interface - then you're relying only on fact, that your parameter follows the contract, provided be that interface. The whole idea of interface is that contract - and you shouldn't be aware neither of specific implementation details, nor even what would be that implementation

Comment: @AlmaDo, so if I understand you, If my SomeClass will iplement LoaderInterface, and then I will call  addLoader($format, SomeClass $loader) , it will be fine ?

Comment: If you have a class that implements `LoaderInterface` it will have to contain all of the methods that the interface states, in this case just `public function load($resource, $locale, $domain = 'messages')` (https://github.com/symfony/Translation/blob/master/Loader/LoaderInterface.php). The interface is just an empty class that state what methods must be present in any class that implements it.

Comment: @Qoop, I know what is the interface, I didnt know how TranslationLoader class will be know what realization hidden behind LoaderInterface $loader load() method, but now I think it more clearly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface injection [is a thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Interface_injection_comparison), but really what you see in the snippet is [Type Hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), a form of [strong typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing).

What this does, is enforce at runtime that the value passed into `$loader` must match the definition of the interface (or class) specified in the type hint. Basically, an answer to the question:

> Does `$loader` implement all the methods of `LoaderInterface`?

If it doesn't, you'll get a [catchable fatal error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting).