# Type checking a PHP function before calling it

Tags: php, types, reflection, php-8

I have a webservice that will be used something like that:

`GET http://localhost/services/sum?a=1&b=2`

This will resolve directly (ignore details like authorization) on a function call defined something like this:

```php
class Services {
    public function sum(int $a, int $b) {
        return $a + $b;
    }
}
```

Now, if they user calls `GET http://localhost/services/sum?a=abc&b=2`, this is a PHP type error. Before calling the `sum` function, I want to "type check" the arguments and report what's wrong. In this case, the response would be something like

```json
"errors" {
    "a": {
        "type_mismatch": {
            "expected": "int",
            "received": "string",
        }
    }
}
```

For this purpose, I wrote this function:

```php
function buildArguments(array $arguments, $service)
{
    $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionFunction($service);
    $reflectionParameters = $reflectionMethod->getParameters();
    $missingArguments = [];
    $typeMismatch = [];
    foreach ($reflectionParameters as $reflectionParameter) {
        $name = $reflectionParameter->getName();
        if (!array_key_exists($name, $arguments) && !$reflectionParameter->isOptional()) {
            $missingArguments[] = $reflectionParameter->getName();
        } else if ((is_null($arguments[$name] ?? null) && !$reflectionParameter->getType()->allowsNull()) ||
            !($reflectionParameter->getType()->getName() == gettype($arguments[$name]))) {
            $typeMismatch[$name] = [
                'received' => gettype($arguments[$name]),
                'expected' => $reflectionParameter->getType()->getName()
            ];
        }
    }
    $errors = [];
    if (!empty($missingArguments)) {
        $errors['missing_argument'] = $missingArguments;
    }
    if (!empty($typeMismatch)) {
        $errors['type_mismatch'] = $typeMismatch;
    }
    if (empty($errors)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        var_dump($errors);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It works well for strings:

```php
function concat(string $a, string $b) {
    return $a . $b;
}
buildArguments(['a' => 'x', 'b' => 'y'], 'concat'); //ok!
buildArguments(['a' => 'x'], 'concat'); // missing_argument: b
buildArguments(['a' =>  1, 'b' => 'y'], 'concat'); //type mismatch: a (expected integer, got string)
```

It immediately falls apart for int:

```php
function sum(int $a, int $b): int
{
    return $a + $b;
}
buildArguments(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2], 'sum');
//type mismatch! expected "int" received "integer"
```

I only need this to work for simple structures: ints, string, untyped arrays, no need to check object, inheritances, interfaces and whatnot.
I could just add a "if int then integer" but I have a feeling there will be a bunch of gotchas regarding nullables and optionals.
Is there a clever way of achieving this?

The TypeError doesn't offer any help in that regard, only a stringified message, maybe I can "manually" call whatever procedure PHP calls that throws the TypeError?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I catch a "catchable fatal error" on PHP type hinting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468487/how-can-i-catch-a-catchable-fatal-error-on-php-type-hinting)

Comment: Thought about just validating input on a case by case basis? Reflection seems overkill and messy. Maybe look at design patterns like validating with a *service layer*?

Comment: @DigiLive no. I know I can catch the TypeError, but I only get a stringified message similar to "sum(): Argument #1 ($a) must be of type int, string given". I can theoretically parse this message and give it back to the user, but that's not what I want.

Comment: @ficuscr my goal is exactly not having to rely on handcrafted validation and leverage statically typed information as much as possible.

Comment: Would use the "statically typed information" but maybe build on common patterns like exception handling. Feel like this approach is limiting. Is your validation of a string going to be limited to it being a string?

Comment: If you're really wanting to pursue this you might want to explore [ReflectionAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.reflection.php).

Comment: Also, if they're get variables, then they're all strings, aren't they? `?a=1` makes `$_GET['a']` equal to `'1'`. It's only PHP's easygoing approach to data types that allows you to use it like an integer. I would personally make my own `validate_integer()` function to handle integers... it would take much less code than your example.

Comment: You could use the php 8.0 `get_debug_type` function instead of `gettype`.

Answer (score -1):

As [Stevish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2418564/stevish) pointed out in a comment, your current approach won't work once you apply it to URLs rather than hard-coded test values, because `$_GET['a']` will only ever be a string (or not set).

Instead, you'll need to look at the expected type, and choose an appropriate validation function. Unfortunately, PHP doesn't have a nice built-in function for "is-integer-ish string" so you'll probably need to use a regex ([`ctype_digit()`](https://php.net/ctype_digit) is close, but won't allow negative numbers, since '-' is not a digit).

To avoid too much spaghetti, I'd break the code for validating out of the loop, and have something like this:

```
    $reflectionMethod = new \ReflectionFunction($service);
    $reflectionParameters = $reflectionMethod->getParameters();
    $errors = [];
    foreach ($reflectionParameters as $reflectionParameter) {
        $name = $reflectionParameter->getName();

        $errors[] = $this->validateParameter(
            $name,
            $reflectionParameter->getType(),
            $arguments[$name] ?? null
        );
    }
```

and then

```
private function validateParameter(string $name, \ReflectionType $expectedType, ?string $input): ?string {
    if ( $input === null )
        if ( !$expectedType->allowsNull() ) {
            return "Missing required $name";
        }
        else {
            // null allowed, no error
            return null;
        }
    }

    switch ( $expectedType->getName() ) {
        case 'string':
            // everything's a string
            // unless you want to assume empty string is always an error?
            return null;
        break;
        case 'integer':
            if ( ! preg_match('/^-?[0-9]+$/', $input) ) {
               return "Bad integer for $name";
            }
        break;
        // Other cases ...
    }
}
```